# Построение графика с отображением времени через заданный интервал

Tags: python, pandas

Есть [датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uAxjSDQIISWr5Ng0sJavgATuGefIK1SI/view?usp=sharing), содержащий массив временных меток в формате (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) и массив чисел с плавающей запятой, каждый из которых соответствует значению в массиве timestamp.

Нужно построить график изменения чисел с плавающей запятой от времени так, чтобы по оси х отметки времени стояли через суточный интервал. График с недельным интервалом строится кодом

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from dateparser import parse

data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', parse_dates=[0], encoding='utf-8', decimal=',', header=None)
data["Date_parsed"] = data[0].map(parse)
x = data["Date_parsed"]
y = data[2]
plt.figure(figsize=(18,8))
plt.title("Изменение величины по времени")
plt.ylabel("Величина")
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Попытка построить график, разбив его между минимальным и максимальным значением дат от x.min() до x.max() завершается ошибкой и непонятно, как при таком формате даты объявлять шаг в сутки.

```
x_range = list(range(x.min, x.max))
```

Как отобразить все значения, какие есть, но нарисовать метки по оси x с частотой в сутки?

Comment: Сформулируйте чётче. Вы хотите отобразить все значения какие есть, но нарисовать метки по оси `x` с желаемой частотой? Или вы хотите отобразить данные только на начало каждых суток, выкинув остальные данные? Или вы хотите аккумулировать данные за каждые сутки и отобразить эти аккумулированные (сумма, медиана, скользящее среднее с окном...) данные на начало каждых суток? Вариантов такого отображения полно, и делаются они все по-разному.

Comment: @CrazyElf отобразить все значения какие есть, но нарисовать метки по оси x с частотой в сутки. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Тогда наверное так https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: И здесь посмотреть https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html

Comment: @CrazyElf Ключевое слово  "наверное "

Comment: Вы пробовали? Что получилось, что нет?

Comment: @CrazyElf Разрываюсь между дать Вам развернутый ответ на каком-нибудь стороннем ресурсе или забить, потому что после ознакомления с приведенными Вами линками этот ответ очевиден.

Comment: Ну если вам всё очевидно, то я рад. У меня лично два варианта, как можно понять ваши слова.